# how to write this regex with fixed length and many elements

Tags: c#, java, regex

the string start with character following with number(both the character and number can be empty), but the total length should be no more than 8.

my solution is

```
([a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*){0,8}
```

seems like total length 8 cannot work, so how to do that

Comment: Why did you tag c# and java..?

Answer (score 2):

To check length of string with regex you can use [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism and add `(?=^.{0,8}$)` at start of regex. `^` is anchor representing beginning of data, `$` represents end.

But in your case I would probably use something like

```
someString.matches("^(|[a-zA-Z]\\d{0,7})$")
```

It will accept

- empty String,
- String containing only one letter at start and up to 7 digits.

Comment: but the character might be 2 length

Comment: @SanqiangZhao Could you [[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15709526/edit)] your question and provide examples of correct and incorrect Strings because `string start with character following with number` is to vague for me. I have few ideas of regex but would like to see which one to post :)

Comment: @SanqiangZhao which of these Strings should are correct: `""`, `"a"`, `"1"`, `"1b"`, `"ab"`, `"a1"`, `"b11"`, `"b1b"`, `"aa12"`, `"a1b2"`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work `([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){0,8}`

If not try 
use this tool [gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)
Or [www.rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/)

Comment: This does not require that the first character, if present, is a letter. "0" would pass this expression.

Comment: ok add `^` to be like `^([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){0,8}` to pass only the start words

Comment: That still doesn't solve the problem, which is that `([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])` is allowing any letter or any number. You would need something like a letter followed by 1-7 of any letter/number, the make the whole thing optional.